# Can I directly connect a wifi-antenna to an NRF24L01 chip without SMA-connector?

Tags: antenna, nrf24l01

I have an NRF24L01 wireless communication chip with an onboard, copper trace antenna. I saw a guide on soldering a wire to the end of the copper trace in order to extend the signal/reception.

I happen to have an antenna with SMA-connector from an old wifi-router laying around. Would it work to connect this to the PCB-antenna copper trace via just soldering a wire to the PCB and stuffing the other end in the antenna SMA connector? Or do you need to consider grounding/power output etc?

Comment: Could you link the guide, please? NRF24L01 is 2.4 GHz. Is the WiFi router antenna also for 2.4 GHz?

Comment: You should add on an SMA receptacle as close as possible to traces. And make it rugged.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Here is the guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpMnauHeR7Y The router had 2.4 GHz and 5GHz bands.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I suppose that's what I SHOULD do :) But I'm wondering if I COULD do it this more brutish way.

Comment: Cut off SMA and solder where it belongs with pigtail wire very short around shld. Make it neat and look like the SMA receptacle legs ( short) 1nH/mm